# Cocos2dx Android: Get data from file(assets/*) failed

Tags: android, eclipse, android-image, cocos2d-x

Where do you need to add your images in your Cocos2dx Android project (in Eclipse)?

They're currently in the 'Resources' folder like what is mentioned [on Ray Wenderlich's blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/11338/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-space-game), but I get an error when I run it in the emulator: "get data from (assets/myFileName) failed" for each image.  I also added these images to the assets folder in Eclipse, and it makes no difference.

It works fine on the iOS side.

Any suggestions?

Comment: so, how is the progress? Did you look at my answer? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the actual problem wasn't with the building or copying process.

I had a class I made that would apply the correct prefix to a CCSprite if it was an iphone, ipad, etc.  And I made some changes to the CCMenuItemImage source code to incorporate this file, but the iOS and Android Cocos2dx files are separate, so the Android project wasn't using the new code, and wasn't adding the correct prefix, so it wasn't finding the image.

Thank you everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to run ./build_native.sh in your android folder before run on Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I ran the ./build_native.sh and it completed, but when I ran the project in Eclipse I got the same errors.

Comment: after run the script, did you refresh the eclipse project?

Comment: I did and it's the same problem.

Comment: @jmosesman would you mind to paste a screenshot of your android project in Eclipse with what inside the assets folder?

Comment: @jmosesman and a bit of your code about what files you are trying to load? Another thing to mention is that ios simulator is NOT case sensitive but android is, try to make sure the file names are exactly the same as what it is in the assets folder.

Comment: Although it was my problem that I fixed, you answered first so you get the bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

You no need to add to the assets folder , when you run ./build_native.sh it will automatically add to the assets folder. Check it build successfully without any errors and then import to  eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ran ./build_native.sh and it copied the images to the assets folder, but I got the same error message when I ran it.  The project doesn't show any errors.

Answer (score 0):

This was the same problem I face. Actually I have solved this problem by doing:

1. Run the ./build_native.sh from cygwin. This step to move the asset needed to android project. Dont forget to chmod 777 -R first to your cocos project, i've got an error because the build_native.sh doesn't have permission to move the assets.
2. In eclipse, build it again following this [tutorial](http://www.cnblogs.com/ybgame/archive/2012/06/07/2540693.html). In that link, it shows how to build the cpp source + cocos2d in eclipse.
3. Run as android application, then the .apk will be generated.

Comment: Where do I do chmod 777 -R?  The build_native.sh completes correctly, and the images are copied to the assests folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`const char *path = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathFromRelativePath("testimage.png");`

before giving cocos2d-x your filename.

Comment: This works for one of my images but the rest all error out.  It has to be something with the copying into the project that is weird.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Cocos2d-JS version.

If you have an empty JS file that is imported in your project.json, you will get this very error on Android.

In this case, solution is to not have any empty JS files imported.