# Cocos2D-x HelloCpp for Android unable to build apk from Windows due to permission denied on asset file

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I was trying to run cocos2dx HelloCpp sample project on Android, building from Windows-7 64 bit with Cygwin 64 bit, however, everytime I try to build and run, it complains that permission was denied on "Marker Felt.fnt" file in assets/font folder.

I checked that there's no permission on that file and chmod to give it proper permission, but everytime I try to run again, that file seems to be regenerated and has no permission again...

Does anyone has the same problem? I have been googling and the nearest problem I've found is this:

[Cocos2dx Android: Get data from file(assets/*) failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417748/cocos2dx-android-get-data-from-fileassets-failed)

However, it is quite different. I've tried disabling UAC on my Windows machine, but the problem doesn't go away

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check the `proj.android/build_native.sh`, every time you run the build, the entire assets/* folder will be re-created, and thus, your *chmod* is nullified.

You can chmod after the copy process itself in the `build_native.sh`, place the *chmod* somewhere after cp the `assets/*`

in my case, put

```
chmod 777 -R "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets
```

after copying the assets folder in `build_native.sh` like this:

```
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    cp "$file" "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets
fi

chmod 777 -R "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets
done
```