# eclipse error (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')

Tags: android

I am working on app but on the console show this error.I have spent my whole day but does not get any success please help.

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744119/unable-to-process-assets-while-packaging-cocos2d-x-android

Comment: not clear by this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have copied some of your project files or folders from Mac to PC, some of the hidden files are also copied automatically which may also raise this issue (files such as ._.DS_Store, etc.)

```
(skipping file '._.DS_Store' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error, it is due to how Google ADT plugin outputs information in Verbose build mode (it shows it in red like an error).

You can hide that by changing the setting below back to default (from `Verbose` to `Normal`):

```
Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Android > Build > Build output = Normal
```